# What is the output from this short string of cdr/car commands?

Tags: scheme, racket

I am trying to understand how multiple calls of car and cdr work together. For example, the following example seems simple enough:

```
(car (cdr '(car (cdr (1 2 3))))
```

My DrRacket compiler outputs `'(cdr (1 2 3))` when it is run, but I don't see how. Shouldn't cdr of (1 2 3) be taken first? What about the first two car and cdr?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, the quote operator will quote all forms and sub forms that follow it.  Only the first car and cdr of the list are executed; first `(cdr '(car (cdr (1 2 3)))` -> `'((cdr (1 2 3))`, and then `(car '((cdr (1 2 3)))` -> `'(cdr (1 2 3))`.

Comment: I think I understand what you're saying, but I'm still not certain. Can you maybe explain what happens a little more?

Comment: Ooh, ok, so it's sort of going "backwards". Starting from the inside going out. I had that switched in my mind because I was turned around by the quote, so it wasn't making any sense! Thanks!

Comment: The quote stops evaluation of the whole list it encloses.

Comment: I just updated your example to use the same syntax for inputs and outputs, and not to use the "write" syntax that hides the quote; the "write" syntax raises questions like, "where did that quote come from" in the beginning of the second step.  Feel free to undo my edit if you think I'm a Communist.

Answer (score 3):

The problem here is that "quote" is much more powerful than you think it is.  In particular, the quote is an instruction to the "reader"--the very first piece of code to examine your program--to rewrite your program from

```
(car (cdr '(car (cdr (1 2 3))))
```

...into

```
(car (cdr (list (quote car) (list (quote cdr) (list 1 2 3))))
```

That is, quote trickles down and changes every left paren into a new list creation, and every identifier into a quoted symbol.

Applying quote to things other than identifiers (e.g., `'abc`) is a fairly slippery concept, and usually makes more sense after you have lots of experience with lists, and are looking for a nice way to abbreviate them.